# How to avoid propagation when chaining Promise with Non-Promise calls

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want the following code not to call OK logic, nor reject the promise. Note, I've a mixture of promise and non-promise calls (which somehow still managed to stay `thenable` after returning a string from its non-promise step), I just want the promise to stay at `pending` status if `p1` resolves to non-OK value.

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("NOT_OK_BUT_NOT_A_CATCH_NEITHER");
});

p1.then(result => {
    if (result !== "OK") {
        return "How do I avoid calling OK logic w/out rejecting?";
    }
    else {
        return Promise.resolve("OK");
    }
}).then(result => {
    console.error("OK logic...");
});
```

Comment: When you use a Promise, You either win with a resolve or you lose with a reject. There is no middle ground. pun intended

Comment: Not resolving will keep you at the middle ground. Not sure how good it is from the memory management etc. - but it does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two options:

1) throw an error:

```
p1.then(result => {
  if (result =='notOk') {
    throw new Error('not ok');
  } else {
    return 'OK';
  }
})
.then(r => {
  // r will be 'OK'
})
.catch(e => {
  // e will be an error with message 'not ok', if it threw
})
```

the second `.then` won't run, the `.catch` will.

2) decide what to do in the latter `.then` conditionally:

```
p1.then(result => {
  if (result =='notOk') {
    return 'not ok'
  } else {
    return 'OK';
  }
})
.then(r => {
  if (r === 'OK') {
    // do stuff here for condition of OK
  }
})
```

This works because the second `.then` takes as an argument whatever was returned by the previous `.then` (however if the previous .then returned a Promise, the second .then's argument will be whatever was asyncronously resolved)

Note: if you `.catch` a promise that errored, and you return THAT promise, the final promise WON'T have an error, because the `.catch` caught it.

Comment: Don't like rejecting as it's not an error, it's just something not worth processing. Extra then - might work, but I think I'm better off with the explicitly pending promise.

Comment: Pending promise is a (very minor) memory leak. You have an option to return your result as a packaged object, `if (isOK(result)) {
            resolve({result:result, status:'OK'});
        }`, and then in your next `.then` you can check the status, and if it's not 'OK' just return null immediately or something

Comment: but then again I'll have to find a way of preventing it from leaking to the next 'then' and so forth, I'd rather cut it off early.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't know if it was getting chained or not.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to not chain that way. Instead do this:

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("NOT_OK_BUT_NOT_A_CATCH_NEITHER");
});

p1.then(result => {
    if (result !== "OK") {
        return "How do I avoid calling OK logic w/out rejecting?";
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve("OK")
            .then(result => {
                console.error("OK logic...");
            });
    }
})
```

If you're writing a linear chain, that means you're saying that you want step by step execution, which isn't what you want in this case.

Alternatively, if your target platforms/build system support it, write it as an async function:

```
(async function() {
    const result = await Promise.resolve "NOT_OK_BUT_NOT_A_CATCH_NEITHER");

    if (result !== "OK") {
        return "How do I avoid calling OK logic w/out rejecting?";
    } else {
        await Promise.resolve("OK");

        console.error("OK logic...");
    }
})();
```

Comment: The function is part of the chain - returning from it results in an original problem.

Answer (score -1):

Found a way, not sure how good is it but it works. The idea is to have it as promises all the way and just not resolve when not needed.

In my case it saves me a hassle with managing ignorable results without polluting result with the likes of `processable` flags.

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("NOT_OK_BUT_NOT_A_CATCH_NEITHER");
});

p1.then(result => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (result === "OK") {
            resolve(result);
        }
        // OR do nothing
        console.error("Just Do nothing");
    });
}).then(result => {
    console.error("OK logic...");
});
```